# How to p4 sync with a condition that all files that need update remain below versions determined by an upper bound changelist?

Tags: perforce

I need a way to sync my workspace, but specify that all files remain at versions that are always below or at versions determined by an upperbound changelist.

So i need to give an input say -cl  to p4 sync , so that all files that need to update, get updated with the restriction, that their target synced version always remain below their depot versions uptill the input CL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like most commands, `p4 sync` accepts a file specification and/or revision specifier argument.  "Everything up to CHANGELIST" is just the revision specifier `@CHANGELIST`.  Hence:

```
p4 sync @CHANGELIST
```